# Simple shell. Mixed pipes and output

Tags: linux, shell, pipe

Let's consider:

```
 cat > outout.txt | cat > outout2.txt
```

I don't know how to interpret something like this. What is the input for the second command?

Comment: if you wanted to cat to both files, check out 'tee'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When cat doesn't receive a filename argument, it takes input from STDIN and sends it to STDOUT, so the effect of the first part of the command chain is to put whatever is typed (until EOD) into the file outout.txt:

```
cat > outout.txt
```

If all goes normally, this command produces no output, and so the second part of the command chain gets nothing to put into outout2.txt:

```
cat > outout2.txt
```

So the file outout2.txt is made empty by the full command chain:

```
$ cat > outout.txt | cat > outout2.txt
```

Note, however, that outout2.txt *will* get some output if the first "cat" invocation generates output. For example, if outout.txt cannot be modified and we send STDERR output to STDOUT:

```
$ chmod a-w outout.txt
$ cat 2>&1 > outout.txt | cat > outout2.txt
```

then outout.txt will be empty, but the following text will be written to outout2.txt (the exact text of the message may depend on your shell - I'm using bash 3.2):

```
-bash: outout.txt: Permission denied
```

Comment: Technically, it's not the first `cat` generating the error message, it's the subshell created by the pipe that executes `cat`. Once the shell fails to open `outout.txt`, the first `cat` is never run.

Comment: Also, `outout2.txt` isn't unchanged; it's truncated by the `>` operator regardless of what else happens in the pipeline.

Comment: @chepner, you're right of course about the contents of outout2.txt being overwritten, and I have corrected my answer. As for the source of the error message, I wrote that it was generated by "the first cat invocation", which means "cat 2>&1 > outout.txt", which is of course the command being executed by the first of the two subshells implied by the pipe symbol. And the distinction between "a command" and "the shell which runs a command" is typically elided when talking about command line operations.

Answer (score 1):

The pipeline is set up before the output redirections are processed. Two subshells are created, each of which inherits its files from the parent. The standard output of the first subshell is used as the standard output of the second subshell. However, the first `cat` doesn't use the file it inherits for standard output; it uses `outout.txt`. As a result, nothing is ever written to the standard input of the second `cat`, so it detects an end-of-file on its first read and exits without writing anything to `outout2.txt`. The standard input of the first `cat` is written to `outout.txt` as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Well, let's try it:

```
$ echo "hello" | cat > outout.txt | cat > outout2.txt 
$ cat outout.txt 
hello
$ cat outout2.txt
```

It appears that, for bash, the `>` redirection has a higher priority than the pipe.